# High Connections issue

Tags: java, struts-1, c3p0

My prod Java EE application using Struts 1.1 and plain JDBC is hosted in OC4J (10g) app server.

I have very strange issue in my live application. Sometime it opens around 1000 connections. I am using C3P0 as connection pool library and have set a max connection limit of 1000 connections. Actually even 500 connection should be more than enough in normal cases. I have a job runs every 30 sec to log number of busy, idle and total connection in the pool.Even in peak time this count never gets more then 200 connections.However sometimes it suddenly opens upto 1000 connection. The log shows that that about 800 connections were busy at that point in time. After another 30 sec the count gets back to the normal.

I am also logging when a connection is acquired and released (for example com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@1fa6aea was acquired and later when it was released) I can confirm there is no leakage in this process. All the connection which were acquired in were released back to pool.

I am not sure if the information above are sufficient enough to answer. Let me know if an extra information is needed.

Comment: Are you logging how long the connections remain in use before being returned to the pool? It sounds like you're taking connections from the pool and keeping them for a long time before returning them.

Comment: In our Environment it happens when we use Tomcat with commons-dpcp and c3p0. We where trying to find the root cause but we cannot found anything at last we used bonecp connections pooling it fixed. But we could not found anything on this issue.

Comment: @Jeff I immediately return the connection to pool once the process is completed . Actually in every function's finally block. Even in the long i can see connection's close method is called either immediately after it is acquired OR a few lines after the call.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "about 800 connections were bust at that point in time." Thanks.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Sorry for the typo I mean 800 connections were busy. I am getting connection count from ComboPooledDataSource.getNumConnections(),ComboPooledDataSource.getNumIdleConnections() and ComboPooledDataSource.getNumBusyConnections(). The last function has returned 811 which I have logged in DB.

Comment: 800 busy Connections! wow. are there 800 active client Threads? can you sample your VM's thread stack traces when you see one of these apparet spikes in usage? [ see e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces() ]

Comment: @SteveWaldman This has been quite long already but I was tracing for the correct log to find out active threads when connection goes high. This happens quite random and once in a two months or so. After setting up trace for active threads when connection usage is high, I got one instance yesterday when C3P0 pool was showing there were 207 busy connection however when I checked the thread trace log I could only see 89 thread.

Comment: @SteveWaldman I am not sure how could I share my logs with yourself , If I need to. Just wondering if there is anything else I can do to reach to the root cause of this problem.

Comment: You haven't posted any config, but from what I'm reading my guess is you need a higher value of [numHelperThreads](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#numHelperThreads). If you have only 89 client Threads but 207 busy Connections, it sounds like c3p0's Thread pool is getting backed up checking Connections back into the pool.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Thanks for the updates our application has following settings minCount=2,maxCount=1000,maxConnectionAge=43200,numHelperThreads=6,unreturnedCon‌​nectionTimeout=1800,maxIdleTime=1800,maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=1000,statementC‌​acheNumDeferredCloseThreads=1

Comment: hopefull `minCount` and `maxCount` are really `minPoolSize` and `maxPoolSize`? if your pool is dealing with hundreds of Connections, consider setting `numHelperThreads` to ~15 or 20. if you monitor by JMX, you can check to see whether the Thread pool is getting backed up under load. You can get a count of task pendings, a status string that lists the tasks, sample Thread pool stack traces, etc.

Comment: @Steve Waldman Yes correct minCount and maxCount are actually minPoolSize and maxPoolSize. Thanks for your suggestion I hope this will help. I will set this up and monitor from there on and let see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application load tested for ~800-1000 concurrent users?

This could be because your database is becoming a bottleneck when responding to requests during peak load. If you use tomcat's jdbc connection pool, it has properties to detect [connection leaks](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/#Connection_leaks) or abandon connection that are open for a long time than the configured timeout. Refer to [this](https://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) link.

Comment: no we never tested 800-1000 concurrent users. It looks impossible too that many user to access the app. we do not have more than 200 active users accessing app in peak time. The DB bottleneck could have been a reason but we checked this the DB didn't show any locks  and the activity graph was pretty normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any ORM frameworks, your JDBC code should be written as follow.
Note that connection is closed in finally block and not in the try block.

```
try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: We are not using any ORM and in the application it is already done like that as you have suggested. I can confirm none of the connection is left open, that means connection is always closed in finally.